# Want to organize the table and built the website in html

Tags: html, r, html-table

The table is going out of range. The temperature unit, maximum and minimum aren't showing. This is how it looks when I don't use `knitr::kable`:

```
## Rows: 1
## Columns: 8
## $ Date        <chr> "2022-05-10T07:00:00+02:00"
## $ EpochDate   <int> 1652158800
## $ Temperature <df[,2]> <data.frame[1 x 2]>
## $ Day         <df[,5]> <data.frame[1 x 5]>
## $ Night       <df[,5]> <data.frame[1 x 5]>
## $ Sources     <list> "AccuWeather"
## $ MobileLink  <chr> "http://www.accuweather.com/en/de/hamburg/20095/daily-weat…
## $ Link        <chr> "http://www.accuweather.com/en/de/hamburg/20095/daily-weat…
```

```
forecast_df <- my_content_json$DailyForecasts
dplyr::glimpse(forecast_df)
knitr::kable(head(forecast_df[,1:8]),"simple", align = "c" )
```

And this is how it looks after using the `knitr::kable`, but I don't see any border for the table. And the links are crossing the boundaries of the website:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions.